# bind flat data source to accordion

Tags: .net, ajax

I have an OLAP cube that I would like to bind to an accordion.

My steps to get the data are through a stored procedure which ends up as a flat datatable in .net; it looks something like this:

```
dimension1, meaure1, measure2, measure3
---------------------------------------------------
header1, 1, 2, 3
header1, 2, 3, 4
header1, 3, 4, 5
header2, 4, 5, 6
header2, 6, 7, 8
header3, 7, 8, 9
 ... etc.

In the accordion, I would like it to be displayed as such:
header1
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
header2
4,5,6
6,7,8
header3
7,8,9
```

In the ItemDataBound event, I wanted to created a label header, then add each measure to a datagrid, much like John did here:  http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=283.

Problem is, for each item in the datatable, .net wants to create a new accordionPane and the event gets hit twice for each record (once as a header and once as an item).  I wanted to use the databind method because I figured it would be much easier to maintain down the road (since I need the event hookups).

I cannot cancel the itemdatabound event.  Also, the accordion.datasource property only accepts a dataview, so I can't pass in a dataset and manipulate it.

My assumption is the databinding is not the proper route.

I appreciate any insight anyone has in attempting to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with accordions, but the following works for nested grids and repeaters, maybe you can adapt.

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Measure1 { get; set; }
    public string Measure2 { get; set; }
    public string Measure3 { get; set; }
}
```

In your method to databind the accordion:

```
DataItem[] dataList = GetData();

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DataItem>> groupedList = dataList.GroupBy(x => x.Header);

AccordionControl.DataSource = groupedList;
AccordionControl.DataBind();
```

Then in the Accordion's `ItemDataBound` event:

```
var group = (IGrouping<string, DataItem>)e.Item;

HeaderLabel.Text = group.Key;

GridControl.DataSource = group;
GridControl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yeah; the trick is creating an array of a special object and setting that to your datasource.  Thanks for the tip!